Is that called "a paper sleeve", "a paper bag", "a paper folder", or "a paper file"?

Source
The above picture shows a flat plastic bag with a flap for containing A4 sheets or pens.
Is it called "a paper sleeve", "a paper bag", "a paper folder", or "a paper file"?
According to my study, a paper sleeve has no flap like this.

Source
A folder looks like this

Source
A file is thicker and looks like this

Source

A "paper bag" is a bag made of paper, a "paper sleeve" (which I don't think exists) would be a sleeve made of paper used for protecting or carrying A4 sized documents.  Paper things would not mean their purpose is to keep or protect documents/photocopies/photos etc from creasing or spoilinng.

"Paper sleeve" makes me think of the paper things open placed around a hot cup of coffee.

'Banner UK' a huge British office-supplies company, calls those things document wallets, and so do I and all the people in my office.

@MichaelHarvey  Wallets! Of course. I wracked my brains to find the best term.

For a UK user, the second picture shows punched pockets sometimes called polypockets

@Mari-LouA - https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/rack-vs-wrack

Yes, a folder in the third picture, and the bottom picture, to be exact, is of lever arch files. When I did stationery ordering, I always made the requesting person show me an example because they almost always called them ring binders which are a different thing.

Don't get me started on comb binding!

And I call my wallet a leather money envelope with credit card compartments.

@TimR - I call mine my purse, which kind of annoys my wife and kids. It's made of tough cloth and is held closed by means of Velcro.

@MichaelHarvey  polypockets are not to be confused with the homophone Polly Pockets

@bradimus yes, though they'd normally be "cardboard sleeves" at least in British English.

If you were going to the stationery supply store wanting one of the items shown in the top photo, the one with the flap, you could ask for a transparent protective envelope, a cellophane envelope, a plastic envelope.  If it can hold a sheet of 8.5 x 11 printer paper in the US (or A4 in the UK) without the paper having to be folded, mentioning the size would be an important detail to clarify what you're looking for. Also, it appears to have a "snap closure". Some variants might have a little button-shaped disk on the flap, and one on the envelope proper, and a bit of string that gets wound around them in a sort of figure-8.

I'm upvoting because I think it's yet another example where the UK and USA have different names for the same item. I can see why "envelope" would work because of its appearance, it looks like an envelope! On the other hand, "wallet" defined as “a pocket-sized flat folding case for holding money and plastic cards” also makes sense–it stores paper sheets–and I remember British colleagues using  that word

@Mari-LouA   A4 is not "pocket-sized". Are you sure your British colleagues were using the term "wallet" of something to hold a large format item like A4?

No A4 is not pocket-sized but the OP's clear wallet is a biggun, and size doesn't matter. Besides it's how you use it that counts. Yes, absolutely certain that the term wallet with that button thing, was called a wallet by more than one British colleague.

Washington's Dream - SNL… a melting pot of different measurements that will make Europeans throw little tantrums…

I always called the first item a [plastic] document wallet when they were made for A4 / Letter sized paper. I've experience of both Us and UK firms and the name seems to be the same on both sides of the pond.

Not just the UK for A4 (part of the ISO 216 standard). Everywhere outside North America and parts of Central and South America, I'd say. But I remember foolscap!

@Mari-LouA - those things that we both know as 'wallets' were so popular in my office that my regular three-monthly orders of 500 used to vanish in a couple of weeks, and not for use in the office. My solution was to deliberately over-order and leave a pile for people to take, putting everyone on their honour not to take from the main 'official' stock. This worked.

I think (partly @Mari-LouA) that "document" qualifies "wallet" in a similar way to  "large" or "A4".  This would mean that the default pocket-sized  no longer applies (a passport wallet might also be too big for a pocket)

The item in the first picture is made of plastic and hence cannot be called paper something.  It's not a sleeve or bag; folder is also unlikely.
We can call it a plastic document case.

A case is rigid.

@TimR   Cases can also expand and be "soft", e.g. pencil case

@MariLouA   I'm assuming a practical context where the name or descriptive phrase used would give the speaker the best chance of getting what they wanted when the thing doesn't have a universally used name; "a plastic document case" would not be what I'd ask for, since cases are most often rigid.

If you have ever used one of those clear closeable cases, they are in actual fact quite stiff, unlike many pencil cases. I wouldn't enter a stationary and ask for "a soft plastic document case" although it might be understood.

Thanks, @Mari-Lou A.
Alright, I've retracted my earlier edit.
